# Nvidia's driver works at startup, but breaks in the middle

Tags: gpu, nvidia

I'm running GeForce GTX 1080ti on macos 10.13.6(17g65) and want to use tesnorflow-gpu.

https://developpaper.com/tensorflow-1-8-with-gpu-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-6/

Use this site as a reference.
Nvidia web driver 387.10.10.10.10.40.105

CUDA driver 396.148

CUDA toolkit 9.2
has been installed.

And when I rebooted the machine, at first I thought it looked like the first picture and was successful at first glance, but after some time, it became like the second picture.
What is the cause?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G39y3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThU13.png)

Comment: The nvcc -V and kextstat | grep -i cuda. commands are the same as on the site above.
However, if you run 'Test whether CUDA can operate normally:', it stops or says 'CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version Result = FAIL'

Comment: Please use the appropriate tags for your question - this is related to `nvidia`, `cuda`, and `gpu`, not to `tensorflow` or `machine-learning` (edited).

Comment: @desertnaut: This doesn't have any on-topic relation to CUDA either.

Comment: @talonmies OK, it seemed so to me from a quick look, but you probably know better :)

Comment: @desertnaut: "my driver blows up after running some tensorflow code on my GPU" isn't really on-topic for [SO]

Comment: @talonmies agree and voted accordingly

Comment: I haven't installed tensorflow yet.